# Getting console or dmesg contents when unable to login after OS crash

Tags: centos7, ipmi, supermicro, kdump

Our server Supermicro SYS-6016T-U often crashes due to https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=10642 .

Since it's unable to write to disk, crash info isn't saved. I also cannot login using either `IPMI` kvm console or `ssh` to run dmesg.

How to configure it to save its errors to some network location? (actually, `NetworkManager` crashes too, so the network card may lose its config) Or maybe the ipmi device has some buffer for that?

I made a mistake and reserved 100% disk space for software raid. Not sure I can use kdump now

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be looking to configure [kdump](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Kernel_Crash_Dump_Guide/chap-introduction-to-kdump.html). It's pretty good at what it does as it runs a new kernel to capture the state of the old one. I've used it to capture kernel crash data that was later used by RH to patch a kenel bug.

It seems like there is also a work-around for the bug you are experiencing - downgrade your kernel to 3.10.0-229.4.2